# What are the objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript

It is said that all are the objects in javascript. But I found that the primitive values like null, undefined, true, 'foo' are not objects. Is that true?

What are the objects in javascript and what are the non-objects in javascript? What is the primitive value actually?

If I'm understanding the following is true?

```
var str1 = "hello world!"; // primitive value
var str2 = String("hello world!");// object value
```

Comment: Everything but primitive values are objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript has two classes of values

- [Primitives](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.2) - number, string, boolean, undefined, null
- [Objects](http://es5.github.io/#x4.2.1) - all other values, including Arrays and Functions

A major difference between primitives and objects is that primitives are *immutable* and custom/adhoc properties *cannot* be assigned to primitive values.

---

The number, string, and boolean primitive types have corresponding Object types: Number, String, and Boolean. However, there are no corresponding Object types for undefined or null - these values are lonely singletons.

The associated types contain the [prototype] which, when applied with implicit conversions, allows primitives to otherwise "act like" objects in that methods can be invoked on them. For instance, `"foo".trim()` calls the [`String.prototype.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) function.

The Number/String/Boolean functions, when *not* used as constructors, also act as *conversions* to the applicable primitive values.

```
"foo"                       // is string (primitive)
String("foo")               // is string (primitive)
new String("foo")           // is String (object)
"foo" === String("foo")     // -> true
"foo" === new String("foo") // -> false
```

One should generally use the primitive types to avoid confusion.

Comment: is this primitive or object ? "foo" === new String("foo") // -> false

Comment: `"foo"` is evaluates to a primitive string, but `new String("foo")` evaluates to a String object. Under rules of `===`, an Object is only equal to *itself* (it would still have be true if `==` had been used due to implicit conversions).

Answer (score 1):

`It is said that all are the objects in javascript. But I found that the primitive values like null, undefined, true, 'foo' are not objects.`

If you read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), It is already given

> In JavaScript, almost everything is an object. All primitive types
>   except null and undefined are treated as objects. They can be assigned
>   properties (assigned properties of some types are not persistent), and
>   they have all characteristics of objects.

[List of  data types in Javascript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wkd9z69%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)